# Jenkins using the wrong commons-io

Tags: java, jenkins

Ok I'll just reformulate my question with new clues I found as I didn't get an answer with the previous one.
So! 
Jenkins is using the wrong commons-io. 
I'm running version 1.598 of Jenkins. In the "about" section, I can see that it's using commons-io version 2.4.

When I run my maven project on Jenkins, project build is a success, but when Jenkins start running PMD or checkstyle analysis, I have the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.lineIterator(Ljava/io/InputStream;Ljava/nio/charset/Charset;)Lorg/apache/commons/io/LineIterator;
    at hudson.plugins.analysis.util.JavaPackageDetector.detectPackageName(JavaPackageDetector.java:34)
    at hudson.plugins.analysis.util.AbstractPackageDetector.detectPackageName(AbstractPackageDetector.java:25)
    at hudson.plugins.analysis.util.PackageDetectors.detectPackageName(PackageDetectors.java:30)
    at hudson.plugins.checkstyle.parser.CheckStyleParser.convert(CheckStyleParser.java:96)
    at hudson.plugins.checkstyle.parser.CheckStyleParser.parse(CheckStyleParser.java:72)
    at hudson.plugins.analysis.core.AbstractAnnotationParser.parse(AbstractAnnotationParser.java:54)
    at hudson.plugins.analysis.core.FilesParser.parseFile(FilesParser.java:323)
    at hudson.plugins.analysis.core.FilesParser.parseFiles(FilesParser.java:281)
    at hudson.plugins.analysis.core.FilesParser.parseSingleFile(FilesParser.java:239)
    at hudson.plugins.analysis.core.FilesParser.invoke(FilesParser.java:198)
    at hudson.plugins.analysis.core.FilesParser.invoke(FilesParser.java:31)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:989)
...
```

This method (lineIterator(Ljava/io/InputStream;Ljava/nio/charset/Charset;)) exists in commons-io 2.4 so my guess is that Jenkins is using another jar.

I ran a locate on the server for commons-io and here is the result:

```
/etc/nexus/2.10/nexus/WEB-INF/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar
/etc/nexus/sonatype-work/nexus/storage/central/commons-io
/etc/nexus/sonatype-work/nexus/storage/central/.nexus/attributes/commons-io
/etc/nexus/sonatype-work/nexus/storage/central/.nexus/attributes/commons-io/commons-io
/etc/nexus/sonatype-work/nexus/storage/central/.nexus/attributes/commons-io/commons-io/1.4
/etc/nexus/sonatype-work/nexus/storage/central/.nexus/attributes/commons-io/commons-io/2.2
/etc/nexus/sonatype-work/nexus/storage/central/.nexus/attributes/commons-io/commons-io/2.4
/etc/nexus/sonatype-work/nexus/storage/central/.nexus/attributes/commons-io/commons-io/1.4/commons-io-1.4.jar
/etc/nexus/sonatype-work/nexus/storage/central/.nexus/attributes/commons-io/commons-io/1.4/commons-io-1.4.pom
/etc/nexus/sonatype-work/nexus/storage/central/.nexus/attributes/commons-io/commons-io/2.2/commons-io-2.2.jar
/etc/nexus/sonatype-work/nexus/storage/central/.nexus/attributes/commons-io/commons-io/2.2/commons-io-2.2.pom
/etc/nexus/sonatype-work/nexus/storage/central/.nexus/attributes/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.jar
/etc/nexus/sonatype-work/nexus/storage/central/.nexus/attributes/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.pom
/etc/nexus/sonatype-work/nexus/storage/central/commons-io/commons-io
/etc/nexus/sonatype-work/nexus/storage/central/commons-io/commons-io/1.4
/etc/nexus/sonatype-work/nexus/storage/central/commons-io/commons-io/2.2
/etc/nexus/sonatype-work/nexus/storage/central/commons-io/commons-io/2.4
/etc/nexus/sonatype-work/nexus/storage/central/commons-io/commons-io/1.4/commons-io-1.4.jar
/etc/nexus/sonatype-work/nexus/storage/central/commons-io/commons-io/1.4/commons-io-1.4.pom
/etc/nexus/sonatype-work/nexus/storage/central/commons-io/commons-io/2.2/commons-io-2.2.jar
/etc/nexus/sonatype-work/nexus/storage/central/commons-io/commons-io/2.2/commons-io-2.2.pom
/etc/nexus/sonatype-work/nexus/storage/central/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.jar
/etc/nexus/sonatype-work/nexus/storage/central/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.pom
/etc/nexus/sonatype-work/nexus/storage/central-m1/commons-io
/etc/nexus/sonatype-work/nexus/storage/central-m1/.nexus/attributes/commons-io
/etc/nexus/sonatype-work/nexus/storage/central-m1/.nexus/attributes/commons-io/jars
/etc/nexus/sonatype-work/nexus/storage/central-m1/.nexus/attributes/commons-io/poms
/etc/nexus/sonatype-work/nexus/storage/central-m1/.nexus/attributes/commons-io/jars/commons-io-1.4.jar
/etc/nexus/sonatype-work/nexus/storage/central-m1/.nexus/attributes/commons-io/jars/commons-io-2.2.jar
/etc/nexus/sonatype-work/nexus/storage/central-m1/.nexus/attributes/commons-io/jars/commons-io-2.4.jar
/etc/nexus/sonatype-work/nexus/storage/central-m1/.nexus/attributes/commons-io/poms/commons-io-1.4.pom
/etc/nexus/sonatype-work/nexus/storage/central-m1/.nexus/attributes/commons-io/poms/commons-io-2.2.pom
/etc/nexus/sonatype-work/nexus/storage/central-m1/.nexus/attributes/commons-io/poms/commons-io-2.4.pom
/etc/nexus/sonatype-work/nexus/storage/central-m1/commons-io/jars
/etc/nexus/sonatype-work/nexus/storage/central-m1/commons-io/poms
/etc/nexus/sonatype-work/nexus/storage/central-m1/commons-io/jars/commons-io-1.4.jar
/etc/nexus/sonatype-work/nexus/storage/central-m1/commons-io/jars/commons-io-2.2.jar
/etc/nexus/sonatype-work/nexus/storage/central-m1/commons-io/jars/commons-io-2.4.jar
/etc/nexus/sonatype-work/nexus/storage/central-m1/commons-io/poms/commons-io-1.4.pom
/etc/nexus/sonatype-work/nexus/storage/central-m1/commons-io/poms/commons-io-2.2.pom
/etc/nexus/sonatype-work/nexus/storage/central-m1/commons-io/poms/commons-io-2.4.pom
/home/jenkins/.m2/repository/commons-io
/home/jenkins/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io
/home/jenkins/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/1.4
/home/jenkins/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/1.4/_maven.repositories
/home/jenkins/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/1.4/commons-io-1.4.jar
/home/jenkins/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/1.4/commons-io-1.4.jar.md5
/home/jenkins/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/1.4/commons-io-1.4.pom
/home/jenkins/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/1.4/commons-io-1.4.pom.md5
/home/sonarqube-4.5.2/lib/common/commons-io-2.4.jar
/root/nexus-2.10.0-02/nexus/WEB-INF/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar
/usr/share/doc/libcommons-io-java
/usr/share/doc/libcommons-io-java/NOTICE.txt
/usr/share/doc/libcommons-io-java/RELEASE-NOTES.txt.gz
/usr/share/doc/libcommons-io-java/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libcommons-io-java/copyright
/usr/share/java/commons-io-1.4.jar
/usr/share/java/commons-io.jar
/usr/share/maven-repo/commons-io
/usr/share/maven-repo/commons-io/commons-io
/usr/share/maven-repo/commons-io/commons-io/1.4
/usr/share/maven-repo/commons-io/commons-io/debian
/usr/share/maven-repo/commons-io/commons-io/1.4/commons-io-1.4.jar
/usr/share/maven-repo/commons-io/commons-io/1.4/commons-io-1.4.pom
/usr/share/maven-repo/commons-io/commons-io/debian/commons-io-debian.jar
/usr/share/maven-repo/commons-io/commons-io/debian/commons-io-debian.pom
/var/cache/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libcommons-io-java.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libcommons-io-java.md5sums
/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/commons-io
/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io
/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/1.4
/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.2
/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.4
/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/1.4/commons-io-1.4.jar
/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/1.4/commons-io-1.4.jar.sha1
/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/1.4/commons-io-1.4.pom
/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/1.4/commons-io-1.4.pom.sha1
/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.2/commons-io-2.2.jar
/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.2/commons-io-2.2.jar.sha1
/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.2/commons-io-2.2.pom
/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.2/commons-io-2.2.pom.sha1
/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.jar
/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.jar.sha1
/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.pom
/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.pom.sha1
/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/commons-io-2.2.jar
```

As you can see there is some occurences of the commons-io 1.4, which does not contains the missing method! So it must be the one Jenkins uses.

In the log of the project I can see:

```
java -cp /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven-agent-1.6.jar:/usr/share/maven2/boot/classworlds.jar hudson.maven.agent.Main /usr/share/maven2/ /var/cache/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/remoting-2.49.jar /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven-interceptor-1.6.jar 56025
```

And in the locate:

```
/home/jenkins/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/1.4/commons-io-1.4.jar
/usr/share/java/commons-io-1.4.jar
/usr/share/maven-repo/commons-io/commons-io/1.4/commons-io-1.4.jar
/var/cache/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar
/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/1.4/commons-io-1.4.jar
/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.jar
```

So I guess the problem lies somewhere around here, but I have no idea how to fix it!
I can't just remove occurences of commons-io 1.4 from the server as some other programs might use them.
Thank you for your help, 
Guillaume

Comment: Could it be that you have multiple commons-IO libraries on your project classpath? e.g. do you have multiple Maven dependencies that might overlap?

Comment: My project in runing just fine locally, and all the projects I have now have this error, so I think it's a conflict of commons-IO libraries between Jenkins and its plugins. I have a build success on my project, the problem occurs afterward

Answer (score 0):

We found the solution!
It seems that this was cause by the maven version used on the server (2.2).
I upgraded it in Jenkins to 3.2.2 and it now works perfectly!

Comment: I have the same problem and am already using 3.2.2. Reinstalling or updating to 2.2.5 didn't fix it for me.

Comment: Hmm may be try to change the version of your maven plugin